# Azure AD B2C Graph Api - Get/Set profile picture

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

For one of my dashboards I want to show the user their profile picture for obvious personalisation reasons, and offer them the possibility to change it.

Most blog posts and articles on the Microsoft Docs site name a variety of endpoints I can leverage to get this data, but I'm just unable to get this to work with a simple postman call. Since I can't even get the photo, I wouldn't know how to change (update) it either.

The following endpoints don't work:

- `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/photo/$value`
- `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/photo`
- `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{id}/photo?api-version=1.6`
- `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{id}/photo/$value?api-version=1.6`

All of them either result in an "resource 'photo' does not exist, or 'Internal server errors' in the json response.

Note: I can query the graph api perfectly fine for other resources.

Answer (score 0):

If in the latest Graph API. Be sure you have set the correct [permission](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get) in application project config for **GraphScope**:

> For user resource: **User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All**
>
> For group resource: **Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All**
>
> For contact resource: **Contacts.Read, Contacts.ReadWrite**

Some tips for [update photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update):

> Update operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school
>   mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.

Because you operate the Azure B2C tenant user, so you have to use the Azure AD Graph API(api 1.6) but the latest Graph API. In the Azure Graph API, there is not a photo property but we can [get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUserThumbnailPhoto)/[set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser) the thumbnail photo.

Comment: I have all permissions set (allowed all). This is Azure b2c, meaning things work a bit different when it comes to personal or organizational accounts. This is shown by the internal server error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same issue with B2C, try using the "thumbnailPhoto" endpoint.  This worked for me (the GET method, specifically).

https://graph.windows.net/[tenant]/users/[objectid]/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6