# Azure AD B2C - Get thumbnail image for logged in user via REST API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to get thumbnail image/profile picture for my logged in Azure AD B2C user.

I have been reading up but so far nothing has helped.

This is for a Azure Active Directory Graph Client but I would like to get it via Rest for the currently logged in user. I would not like to require an administrator account to get it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/305156f6-d6e9-4134-87b6-043c9c64ac8c/getting-a-profile-picture-under-azure-ad-b2c?forum=WindowsAzureAD

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41056923/3850405

What looked really promising was this endpoint but given that it is `graph.windows.net` I'm not sure it will work given that my permissions later is set for `graph.microsoft.com`.

```
https://graph.windows.net/[tenant]/users/[objectid]/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943064/3850405

Preferably I would like to call an endpoint like this to get the currently logged in users picture but the above endpoint is of course OK.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#request
However to call this

Both of these methods requires a valid bearer token.

What I have done so for is accessing my `Azure AD B2C` and then `App registrations`. Select my application and then `API permissions`. Select `Add a permission`.

Click on Microsoft Graph and then add `profile` as the picture below:

[image]

If I follow the guide for `Get access on behalf of a user` within the Microsoft Graph documentation this will lead to Microsofts login page like this:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

If I do login I will get an error as expected:

[image]

> Sign in Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS50020: User account 'oscar.andersson@' from identity provider ''
> does not exist in tenant '' and cannot access the application ''() in
> that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the
> tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active
> Directory user account.

When I log in to my application normally I get a screen that looks like this. Works perfectly and connects to a instance with a domain name like: `https://<myadb2c>.b2clogin.com/tfp/`.

[image]

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61105325/3850405

If I do login with my administrator account for `Get access on behalf of a user` I do get a code returned without a consent experience.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph/api/1.0#consent-experience

However when I make the POST request to get a token I get the following response:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph/api/1.0#token-request

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named ''. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: \r\nCorrelation ID: \r\nTimestamp: 2020-08-21 12:23:13Z",
    "error_codes": [
        65001
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-08-21 12:23:13Z",
    "trace_id": "",
    "correlation_id": "",
    "suberror": "consent_required"
}
```

According to the documentation:

> The Microsoft identity platform v2.0 endpoint will also ensure that
> the user has consented to the permissions indicated in the scope query
> parameter. If the user has not consented to any of those permissions
> and if an administrator has not previously consented on behalf of all
> users in the organization, they will be asked to consent to the
> required permissions.

Admin consent has been given for the permissions:

[image]

If I change the working login to use scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/profile` instead of `https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<client-id>/read` I will get a code but not a token. Error:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADB2C90205: This
> application does not have sufficient permissions against this web
> resource to perform the operation.\r\nCorrelation ID: \r\nTimestamp:
> 2020-08-21 13:36:44Z\r\n"}

If I try to call `https://graph.microsoft.com/profile` with the token from scope `https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<client-id>/read` I will get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-21T14:02:14",
      "request-id": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I really did not expect it to be this hard to get the profile picture out. Getting the given name and surname is no problem since this information is returned from the `Sign up and sign in (Standard)` `User flow` as claims.

[image]

I have read how I could Manage Azure AD B2C with Microsoft Graph but this is not what I wan't. I don't wan't to create a new App registrations simply because I wan't to fetch an already logged in users thumbnail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [photo endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) is not supported in Azure B2C. You might create a custom API to store and retrieve them using [jQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples), [UI customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) and/or [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview#:%7E:text=Custom%20policies%20are%20configuration%20files,to%20complete%20many%20different%20tasks.) and [REST technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile).

Comment: OK but how can I reach https://graph.microsoft.com/profile then? For `API permissions` -> `Microsoft Graph` -> `Delegated permissions` -> `profile` it says "Allows the app to see your users' basic profile (name, picture, user name)".

Comment: The profile claim is not used by B2C user flows or journeys. You can get the user account resource or "profile" (not the same as the profile endpoint) trough the [Get a user operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but for this you will have to use a standard AAD (not B2C) app registration.

Comment: is it documented somewhere? I mean, that photo endpoint is not supported in azure b2c. It doesn't say anything in the docs as far as I know