# What is the best way to get profile pictures from my users, which have logged in through a Azure B2C from multiple external tenants

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I currently have a user login flow through a B2C working through custom policies, with multiple external tenants. After login i have a Nuxt website which exchange calls with a ASP.NET Core 6 Rest API.

I wish to fetch the logged in user profile picture if they have one. preferably in the Rest API where i would like to store it.

So what would be the best way of getting the profile pictures? And How would one do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Retrieving the user's photo using the Microsoft Graph API is currently not supported in Azure AD B2C tenants.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#to-retrieve-the-profile-photo-of-a-user)

[image]

I also verified it in my side, you also can follow the way to check it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for a workaround?

Comment: @GoWiser I try to upload the avatar in the portal, and click save after uploading. When I refresh the page, the avatar is not updated, so I think there is no workaround.

Comment: @GoWiser The official document clearly stated that it is not supported, and then I tried it from the azure portal, providing an entry to modify the avatar, but the modification failed, which means that we cannot find the available restapi through the http request.

Comment: @GoWiser Of course, if you want, you can [try this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63531728/7687666) by creating custom api.